# Can i store Objects in process.env

Tags: node.js

I'm storing an object (which has several methods) into `process.env` as below:

```
var obj = createObject(); // returns new object
process.env.OBJ = obj;
```

When I access this object from other places like below, I don't see any of the methods.

```
var obj = process.env.OBJ;
```

Showing `[Object Object]`.

Why is that?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? There must be a better solution than putting an object in `process.env`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

process.env is to store your environmental variables not really to store your objects. You can store your variables like that:

```
process.env['CONSUMER_KEY'] = ""
process.env['CONSUMER_SECRET'] = ""
process.env['ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY'] = ""
process.env['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'] = ""
```

Here is a link to it https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

If you want to store your methods you should create a global object and assign your methods to that one.

Answer (score 47):

Short answer is: **NO**

No, you can't store objects in `process.env` because it stores environment variables like `PATH, SHELL, TMPDIR` and others, which are represented by String values. If you run command `console.log(process.env);` you can see all env variables of your system, in particular you can set your own env variables (e.g. `process.env.home = 'home'`) which will be available during the process you run your nodejs application.

**Solution exists!**
Stringify JSON object and save as env variable. Then parse and use it when you need your object

Comment: astonishingly, `dotenv-json` doesn't stringify or parse objects. It just outputs `[Object: object]`

Answer (score 5):

Altho you can't store objects in `process.env` directly, you can still store in `process` itself.

Comment: can you add some example illustrating your answer?

Comment: @stuckoverflow, be patient. They're thinking it over...

Answer (score 2):

Try to stringify the object and pass into the process.env and parse the string to get the object this will work.
Eg.

```
var obj = createObject(); // returns new object

process.env.OBJ = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Use this in code like `let objFromEnv= JSON.parse(process.env.OBJ);`

Comment: I'm trying to add the object in the .env file, how would I do this using your approach

Comment: say add your env as object in the env file as myENVObj={"testObj1":true, "testObj2":"name1"}  and in code 
  let myObj =JSON.parse(process.env.myENVObj);